# Replacing dead hirelings in Pathfinder downtime system

Tags: pathfinder-1e, downtime, followers-and-hirelings

I am currently pricing up the cost of running a mercenary guild for a game I am assisting with (GM for downtime).

I've combined Guildhall and Barracks (while removing duplicates between building types) and placed a Mercenary Company organization in it.

Given the way the player in question plays, sooner or later he is going to get some of his Elite Soldiers and Elite Archers killed off. What would be the best way to handle replacing lost men?

The best I can think of would be to charge 1/5 of the cost per lost man from the unit and deny earnings from that unit until fully restocked. Or would it be better to say that it takes one week per lost man to "heal" through recruitment? I want to strongly discourage using 3rd level characters as cheap disposable meat shields.

Are there actual mechanics for this situation that I have missed and if not is my approach the best idea?

Answer (score 8):

There is no cost for replacing one or two members of a team.

> The composition of a team is flexible and can change over time depending on the nature of your organization. For example, if your thieves’ guild has Cutpurses and Robbers, some of them might get caught and jailed, but it is assumed your organization replaces them with individuals of similar skill. In the same way that you don’t have to track routine maintenance on a building you own, replacing individuals who leave your organization is factored into the price of the team.

Just as it's assumed some thieves will be caught, it is assumed some soldiers will be lost in battle.

---

The price for replacing an entire lost [Team](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/downtime/#TOC-Teams) (I would also apply this if a majority of them are lost) is indicated in their own section:

- Elite Soldiers "**Create** 5 Goods, 3 Influence, 7 Labor (330 gp); **Time** 5 days; **Size** 5 people"
- Elite Archers "**Create** 5 Goods, 4 Influence, 8 Labor (380 gp); **Time** 6 days; **Size** 5 people"

The initial Price of Mercenary company seems to include these numbers.

Comment: Yep this is the cost to hire and equip those guys. Anything after that is already handled by the bonus they grant to downtime checks. So they dont cost anything extra. So if your team of 5 elite soldiers got killed, tough luck, but now you gotta pay another 330 gp (or half that through aquiring goods) to get another team ready for action.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. What I am wondering about is what if one archer is killed? Does this reduce their earning potential by 1/5 is the team dysfunctional and how does the dead person get replaced?

Comment: Ah. I understand the 1/5 portion better now. I don't think there's further guidance, but I'll try to dig deeper and see if I catch something you missed